# purrr combining two crossing with common list

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to use `purrr` to create a path following the form

```
some_path/year/filename_with_year.xls
```

where the files reside in a subdirectory based on the same list of years used to create part of the filename

so far, I am able to create the first part of the path and the filename with `cross3` and `cross2`, but I do not succeed to combine them in a sensible way in a full path

```
library(tidyverse)

year_list<-c(2008,2009,2010, 2011)
country_list<-c("Andorra","Belarus")
remote_base_path<-"some_path"

filename<-cross3(country_list,year_list,".xls") %>%map(lift(paste0)) #create filename
filepath<-cross2(remote_base_path,year_list)%>%map(lift(file.path)) #create path


filename
filepath
```

How can I combine them within the `purrr` logic (e.g. another `cross2` and the use of `.filter`?)?

Another way of looking at it is that the year_list is mapped to two lists, but with other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the best approach, but you can try :

```
l <- cross(list(c(2008,2009,2010, 2011), 
                c("Andorra","Belarus"), 
                "some_path")) %>%
  map(set_names, c("year", "country","remote"))

map_chr(l, ~ glue("{file.path(.$remote, .$year)}/{.$country}_{.$year}.xls"))

[1] "some_path/2008/Andorra_2008.xls" "some_path/2009/Andorra_2009.xls"
[3] "some_path/2010/Andorra_2010.xls" "some_path/2011/Andorra_2011.xls"
[5] "some_path/2008/Belarus_2008.xls" "some_path/2009/Belarus_2009.xls"
[7] "some_path/2010/Belarus_2010.xls" "some_path/2011/Belarus_2011.xls"
```

Comment: Thanks! Using named lists with map_chr and glue is a nice solution. Does the job, is easy understandable, and is easy expandable to more contributing lists.